# ActiveRecord include associations missing records

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

I'm making the following query

```
PortfolioDistribution.joins(:portfolio_distribution_split).
  select('policy_number, reinvestment_date, reinvestment_units,
  reinvestment_units, split_name, split_percentage').
  where(:policy_number => policy_no, :reinvestment_date => period,
  :ods_psgamas_gls_portfolio_distribution_split => { :split_name => type })
```

Which returns 15 records, but the associated model `portfolio_distribution_split` is `nil`. If I change the query to include the associaterd model like so:

```
PortfolioDistribution.joins(:portfolio_distribution_split).
  select('policy_number, reinvestment_date, reinvestment_units,
  reinvestment_units, split_name, split_percentage').
  where(:policy_number => policy_no, :reinvestment_date => period,
  :ods_psgamas_gls_portfolio_distribution_split => { :split_name => type }).
  includes(:portfolio_distribution_split)
```

I only get 3 records? If I take the generated `SQL` and run it directly against the database I get 15 records. What happened to the other 12 records?

- activemodel (3.2.13)
- activerecord (3.2.13)
- activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (3.2.8)
- activeresource (3.2.13)
- activesupport (3.2.13)

Comment: And can you mark me place in `where` where you specify that `portfolio_distribution_split` shoudn't be nil? Because includes (sorry if i'm wrong) use other `join`. Please read about LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN, RIGHT JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was conceputal.

`portfolio_distribution` and `portfolio_distribution_split` have a one-to-many relationship.

When I run the first query I get a record for each `portfolio_distribution_split`.

The second query returns a record for each `portfolio_distribution` with an array of `portfolio_distribution_splits` related to the `portfolio_distributions`